# How to get Excel cell row and col based on cell value using python

Tags: python, xlrd

How to identify cell row and cell col based on xl cell value in python...

sheet.cell(row,col) gives value but if we have value then how to get that corresponding row and col value of the shell

i searched but i could know how to identify cell details based on cell value..

pls help me thanks in advance

Comment: which python module are you using to access excel files? the answer will partly depend on that.

Comment: perhaps I'm mistaken, but I don't think you can unless you loop over all cells and check each value against the target. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778093/pyexcelerator-or-xlrd-how-to-find-search-a-row-for-the-given-few-column-data

Comment: @Oz123  i am using xlrd module........ any other good module to read from excel

Comment: @Fredrik while we read from sh.row(some row) we get a list of values but from that how to get col name and row name together for each value

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/958903/297323 or did I misinterpret you?

Comment: @Fredrik do u know how to get "name range" given for a  particular cell

Comment: @Oz123 hey do u know how to get name range for a particular cell

Comment: @user1182090, no sorry. I am excel free, but my question was necessary. If you want people to be able to help you, you got to help them help you. Providing broad information can ease the process. It is certainly possible that module A does that differently than xlrd.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate over the worksheets, then over the rows in a worksheet and then over the cells in a row. You have to keep track of the row and column number as the xlrd Cell class does not seem to store that:

```
import sys
import xlrd

_ordA = ord('A')

def find_val_in_workbook(wbname, val):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(wbname)
    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.ctype != 2:
                    continue
                if cell.value != val:
                    continue
                if colidx > 26:
                    colchar = chr(_ordA + colidx / 26)
                else:
                    colchar = ''
                colchar += chr(_ordA + colidx % 26)
                print '{} -> {}{}: {}'.format(sheet.name, colchar, rowidx+1, cell.value)

find_val_in_workbook(sys.argv[1], float(sys.argv[2]))
```

call the script with the name of the `.xls` file and the value to search for